# Integrate WooCommerce theme with a Wordpress theme

Tags: theme-development, customization, themes, woocommerce-offtopic

I have some questions about WooCommerce theme's integration into an existing Wordpress theme:

1. Is it possible to integrate a WooCommerce theme into an existing Wordpress theme?
2. Should I make my theme supporting WooCommerce since the project's start or can I add WooCommerce integration to my theme in a second step?
3. What are the steps for integrate WooCommerce into an existing theme? Is it possible or I will have to rebuild the whole theme from scratch?
4. What problems could I meet if I will add it in a later time?

Comment: This is an open ended opinion based question about an off-topic subject. It is really a project management question that has nothing to do with wordpress, when do you start paying attention to phase B while working on phase A. If there was a simple answer you would not have asked the question ;), the answer is just different for each project.

Comment: @MarkKaplun I changed the question in order to be less opinion-based

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would add it from the start so you don't have to go back to it, and it's a really simple process of creating a woocommerce.php file in your theme and then add the following to your functions.php

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'woocommerce_support' );
function woocommerce_support() {
    add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
}
```

To create the woocommerce.php, copy your page.php, remove the loop code and replace with:

```
<?php woocommerce_content(); ?>
```

More info at https://docs.woothemes.com/document/third-party-custom-theme-compatibility/

Comment: Thanks for the reference. What problems could I meet if I will add it in a later time? (What are the steps for integrate WooCommerce into an existing theme?)

Comment: Don't think you will encounter any unless the theme becomes really complex and you need to recode a few things, but personally I would do it from the start and build the site as if it was going to use woocomm from the start

Comment: I've the same problem: I've a Wordpress theme and I need to integrate Woocommerce in it. For example: Can I add the cart in the header, without re-building the theme?